# Inverse of non zero elements of a matrix

Tags: matlab

I want to follow [this example](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee127a/book/login/exa_pinv_4by5.html). Aftes Generating a matrix `S` in matlab I want to inverse the non zero values by `1./A` but that will give me `Inf` for the 0 values which are supposed to stay 0.

How do I invert only the nonzero values?

Comment: after `1./A` add a line that `ans(ans == Inf) = 0` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
B=1./A;
B(isinf(B))=0;
```

And all problems gone!

Alternatively

```
A(A==0)=Inf;
B=1./A;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have many zeros in your matrix, you might want to use `sparse` matrix:

```
A = sparse(A);
B = spfun(@(x) 1./x, A); % inverse only non-zeros
```

Comment: I do not have many zeros but this is a very good tip so I gave you a +1.